# how to delete branch with vscode

Tags: github, vscode

I created three branches on github.How can I delete one branch on vscode? just to workaround this, I delete the branch on github, go back to vscode to pull/synch etc but even though deleted branch does not exist on github, vscode seems to still have it. How can I properly delete a branch on vscode?

Answer (score 4):

Go to View --> select Command Platted option --> select Delete Branch --> and select the local branch which we have to delete

Answer (score 1):

Menu - View - SCM, choose the project then, More actions - Branch - Delete Branch. If branch is deleted on github, on vscode, More actions - Pull,Push-Sync, otherwise vscode still is on old cache.